# Sum values with multiple criteria and with name array as an another criteria

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

I am trying to `SUM` values based on multiple criteria from a Power Query table (SQL download):

- **Type of Error** (*name is hard-coded in cell, easy enough, done, cell reference* `B28` *in code below*)
- **Month** and **Year** of record (*also hard-coded for cell reference, also done*)
- **ID** of the person who recorded that. We have four teams for which I have assigned name range (`MI_Equities`, `M_Bonds`, `SSR_Equities`, `SSR_Bonds`), with list of User IDs. This list is with different length.

Here is the formula that I am working with (*without* last condition):

```
=(SUM(IF((tblAPP_Main[TypeError]=$B28)*(MONTH(tblAPP_Main[DateOccurence])=MONTH($K$2))*(YEAR(tblAPP_Main[DateOccurence])=YEAR($N$2))=1;1;0)))
```

This formula works until I add the below after the year condition:

```
*SUMPRODUCT((--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(MI_Equities;tblAPP_Main[CreatedBy]))))
```

From this formula I get the `#VALUE!` error (for the values in array) and the `#N/A` error for the others. I think I'm getting these errors because the matrix has a different length than the column I want to compare it with, but I'm not sure.

---

**To show it in practice:**

Let's say I have this table (`tblAPP_Main`): 
[image: this table]

and I need to count how many times there is the **je*** specified in the named range (i.e. **je23575** is named `MI_Equities`, so I want to use that name).

This *should* return number **1**, as 1 human mistake was made by that specific team.

I need my final table to look like this:
[image: this].

**Important note:** It should **not** be calculation heavy and **NOT** scripted in VBA.

Comment: I forgott to thanks, if someone even thinks about this. Thank you for your time guys, I am lost on this one for hours.

Comment: If you have "that table" and it was named `tblAPP_Main` and you wanted to count how many times "`JE11221`" occurs in column "Created by" then you could use formula: `=COUNTIF(tblAPP_Main[Created by],"JE11121")`  It looks like you may be missing a space in the table name.  Upper/lower case also matters; you might have some issues because some of the `JE` "numbers" are `je`.  (Fix that however it's getting entered, or use the `UPPER` function at some point before the data gets to this formula.)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new column`tblAPP_Main` called `Team_Name` where you use an `if` function with the team names to populate the column. (Essentially moving your named ranges into the new column)

To populate `Table_Final`, use `=countifs('tblAPP_Main'!$A:$A= tblAPP_Main$A2, 'tblAPP_Main'!$D:$D= 'tblAPP_Main'!B$1)`. (Column D is the new column that you just created.)
The countifs should populate the table and you can use a sum function for the totals.
Please let me know if this helps.